# Inequality in five variables with ordering

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I believe that the following statement is true, but have not been able to prove it myself. Any help would be appreciated!

Let $0 < x \leq y \leq z < w$, and $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$. Then

$\left( \frac{w - z}{w - y} \right)^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}} z \leq \left( \frac{w - z}{w - y} \right)^{\frac{1}{\gamma}}\left( y - \gamma w \right) +\gamma w$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Bernoulli inequality,
$$
  \left(1+\frac{z-y}{w-z}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}\geq1+\frac1\gamma\frac{z-y}{w-z}.
$$
Rearranging,
$$
  1\geq\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}\frac{\gamma(w-z)+(z-y)}{\gamma(w-z)}.
$$
Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \gamma w
    &\geq&\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}\frac{\gamma w(w-z)+w(z-y)}{w-z}\\
    &=&\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}\frac{(\gamma w-y)(w-z)+z(w-y)}{w-z}\\
    &=&\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}\left[(\gamma w-y)+z\frac{w-y}{w-z}\right]\\
    &=&\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma}(\gamma w-y)+\left(\frac{w-z}{w-y}\right)^{\frac1\gamma-1}z\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and the result follows.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!